# How to shred the mentioned XML in sql query

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I would like to shred the below xml in the SQL query using nodes('/Nodes1') in such way so that result should be 2 records in table. Currently, I am reading the xml nodes two times(separately for ChildNode2 and ChildNode3) and insert the data into the table.

```
ChildNode1   Test
 01234        Test1
 01234        Test2
```

XML is like below:

```
<Node1>
 <ChildNode1>01234</ChildNode1> 
 <ChildNode2>Test1</ChildNode2>
 <ChildNode3>Test2</ChildNode3>
</Node1>
```

---

**Edit:** The actual XML is:

```
 <DEBMAS06>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">    
    <E1KNA1M SEGMENT="1">
     <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
     <KUNNR>0000000675</KUNNR>
     <BBBNR>0000000</BBBNR>
     <BBSNR>00000</BBSNR>
     <BEGRU>0001</BEGRU>
     <BRSCH>9000</BRSCH>
     <BUBKZ>0</BUBKZ>
     <KTOKD>0001</KTOKD>
     <KUKLA>SC</KUKLA>
     <LAND1></LAND1>
     <NAME1></NAME1>
     <NAME4></NAME4>
     <ORT01></ORT01>
     <SORTL></SORTL>
     <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
     <STRAS>,</STRAS>
     <TELF1>25950393</TELF1>
     <TELFX>25588160</TELFX>
     <LZONE>0000000001</LZONE>
     <GFORM>06</GFORM>
     <BRAN1>TRAD</BRAN1>
     <BRAN2>TRADINGCO</BRAN2>
     <BRAN3>TRADINGCO</BRAN3>
     <BRAN4>TRAD</BRAN4>
     <UMJAH>0000</UMJAH>
     <JMZAH>000000</JMZAH>
     <JMJAH>0000</JMJAH>
     <UMSA1>0</UMSA1>
     <HZUOR>00</HZUOR>
     <SPRAS_ISO>EN</SPRAS_ISO>
     <E1KNA11 SEGMENT="1">
     <RGDATE>00000000</RGDATE>
     <RIC>00000000000</RIC>
     <RNEDATE>00000000</RNEDATE>
     <LEGALNAT>0000</LEGALNAT>
    </E1KNA11>      
   </E1KNA1M>
  </IDOC>
 </DEBMAS06>
```

My query:

```
SELECT ct1.n.value('KUNNR[1]','NVARCHAR(10)')+ct2.n.value('.','NVARCHAR(10)') AS IDOCID 
FROM @xmlStringOrig.nodes('DEBMAS06/IDOC/E1KNA1M') AS ct1(n)
     CROSS APPLY ct1.n.nodes('/*[local-name()="BRAN1" OR local-name()="BRAN3"]') AS ct2(n)
```

But the above query is giving an error:

> XQuery [ct1.n.nodes()]: No more tokens expected at the end of the XQuery expression. Found 'OR'.

Expected Result should be as below:

```
IDOCID
0000000675TRAD
0000000675TRADINGCO
```

Comment: IIUC, always one root node `<Node1>`, having always 3 subelements `ChildNode1...ChildNode3`?

Comment: Yes..I would like to treat ChileNode1 as parent of ChildNode2 and ChildNode3 and insert the two records in datatable.

Comment: Please add the expected result for this new XML.

Comment: Dear Shnugo..I have added the expected result

Comment: @Mohan, and I have edited my answer...

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT2

This should be your query:

```
SELECT ct1.n.value('KUNNR[1]','NVARCHAR(10)')+ct2.n.value('.','NVARCHAR(10)') AS IDOCID 
FROM @xmlStringOrig.nodes('/DEBMAS06/IDOC/E1KNA1M') AS ct1(n)
     CROSS APPLY ct1.n.nodes('*[local-name()="BRAN1" or local-name()="BRAN3"]') AS ct2(n)
```

#### previous

I must admit that I do not understand what you want to achieve. How should any logic know generically what you want and how to interprete these values?

This works, but it is ugly...

```
DECLARE @x XML=
'<Node1>
 <ChildNode1>01234</ChildNode1> 
 <ChildNode2>Test1</ChildNode2>
 <ChildNode3>Test2</ChildNode3>
</Node1>';

SELECT @x.value('(/Node1/ChildNode1)[1]','varchar(15)') AS NumericValue
      ,@x.value('(/Node1/ChildNode2)[1]','varchar(15)') AS TestCaption
UNION ALL
SELECT @x.value('(/Node1/ChildNode1)[1]','varchar(15)')
      ,@x.value('(/Node1/ChildNode3)[1]','varchar(15)');
```

The result

```
NumericValue    TestCaption
01234           Test1
01234           Test2
```

#### EDIT: Some more approaches:

```
WITH TwoRows(RowInx) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2)
SELECT @x.value('(/Node1/ChildNode1)[1]','varchar(15)') AS NumericValue
      ,CASE WHEN RowInx=1 
            THEN @x.value('(/Node1/ChildNode2)[1]','varchar(15)') 
            ELSE @x.value('(/Node1/ChildNode3)[1]','varchar(15)') END AS TestCaption
FROM TwoRows;

SELECT @x.value('(/Node1/ChildNode1)[1]','varchar(15)') AS NumericValue
      ,Two.Children.value('.','varchar(15)') AS TestCaption
FROM @x.nodes('/Node1/*[local-name()="ChildNode2" or local-name()="ChildNode3"]') AS Two(Children)
```

Comment: Hi Shnugo, Thanks for reply. Currently, I am doing the same instead of union inserting into table variable two times as union is always performance overhead. Instead of inserting two times or union , I would like to insert into table as one shot. Is it not possible?

Comment: Well, it would be possible with tricks, but some questions before: Is your XML really like the example? What are you trying to achieve? Btw: With `ALL` the `UNION` is not more overhead than  your approach. With this there is no implicit search for duplicates...

Comment: @Mohan, please see my edit, there are two other approaches - and I'm sure there would be more...

Comment: Thanks Shungo..Actually the our xml is not exactly like this but for this particular requirement ..the structure is same like that.

Comment: Duplicate check I am doing later when actual insert. By this approach.. I am inserting in Table variables.

Comment: Hi Shnugo.. I have updated the actual xml and select query but getting the error. Can you please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Mohan, Please see my EDIT2... The "OR" must be an "or" and there was a slash to much. But your query was very close to the truth :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

This selects what I believe you want:

---

The xml:

```
DECLARE @x XML=
'<DEBMAS06>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">    
    <E1KNA1M SEGMENT="1">
     <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
     <KUNNR>0000000675</KUNNR>
     <BBBNR>0000000</BBBNR>
     <BBSNR>00000</BBSNR>
     <BEGRU>0001</BEGRU>
     <BRSCH>9000</BRSCH>
     <BUBKZ>0</BUBKZ>
     <KTOKD>0001</KTOKD>
     <KUKLA>SC</KUKLA>
     <LAND1></LAND1>
     <NAME1></NAME1>
     <NAME4></NAME4>
     <ORT01></ORT01>
     <SORTL></SORTL>
     <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
     <STRAS>,</STRAS>
     <TELF1>25950393</TELF1>
     <TELFX>25588160</TELFX>
     <LZONE>0000000001</LZONE>
     <GFORM>06</GFORM>
     <BRAN1>TRAD</BRAN1>
     <BRAN2>TRADINGCO</BRAN2>
     <BRAN3>TRADINGCO</BRAN3>
     <BRAN4>TRAD</BRAN4>
     <UMJAH>0000</UMJAH>
     <JMZAH>000000</JMZAH>
     <JMJAH>0000</JMJAH>
     <UMSA1>0</UMSA1>
     <HZUOR>00</HZUOR>
     <SPRAS_ISO>EN</SPRAS_ISO>
     <E1KNA11 SEGMENT="1">
     <RGDATE>00000000</RGDATE>
     <RIC>00000000000</RIC>
     <RNEDATE>00000000</RNEDATE>
     <LEGALNAT>0000</LEGALNAT>
    </E1KNA11>      
   </E1KNA1M>
  </IDOC>
 </DEBMAS06>';
```

The query:

```
;WITH x AS (
    SELECT 
        kunnr=n.v.value('(KUNNR)[1]','NVARCHAR(10)'),
        bran1=n.v.value('(BRAN1)[1]','NVARCHAR(10)'),
        bran3=n.v.value('(BRAN3)[1]','NVARCHAR(10)')
    FROM 
        @x.nodes('DEBMAS06/IDOC/E1KNA1M') AS n(v)
)
SELECT result=kunnr+bran1 FROM x
UNION ALL
SELECT result=kunnr+bran3 FROM x;
```

If you think you need to ignore namespaces (I don't see why from the XML), eg the `bran1=n.v.value('(BRAN1)[1]','NVARCHAR(10)'),` would become `bran1=n.v.value('*[local-name()="BRAN1"][1]','NVARCHAR(10)'),`

Result:

```
+---------------------+
|       result        |
+---------------------+
| 0000000675TRAD      |
| 0000000675TRADINGCO |
+---------------------+
```